# Is it possible to use segment registers to in an assigment?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, memory-segmentation

i have the following code (working using nasm in 16 bit real mode ):

```
mov bx , 0x0          ;; use es(egmen) register 
mov es , bx           ;; to mov a value in al
mov al , es:0x48      ;; and print 
int 0x10

mov al , 0x48         ;; shouldn't this print 
int 0x10              ;; the same as above ?
```

As far as i know es:0x48 (es=0x0) should evaluate to 0x48.
So the al register must contain that value , though it doesn't . Why this happens ?

Comment: Weird, NASM allows that MASM-like syntax for a memory address, breaking the usual NASM rule that memory operands *always* have `[]` around them.  Disassemble it with `ndisasm -b16 foo.bin` and you'll see  `26A04800      mov al,[es:0x48]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but it doesn't do what you think it does.

The instruction

```
mov al, es:0x48
```

loads a byte from address `es:0x48` into `al`.  This will only load `0x48` into `al` if the byte at address `es:0x48` holds `0x48`.

The x86 instruction set has no instruction to compute linear addresses.  Even something like

```
lea ax, es:0x48
```

will only give you `0x48` (i.e. the offset into the segment) regardless of what `es` holds.